# T-SQL Calculate time between changing status per hour

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

**EDIT:** *I changed my example and made it more simple. First Quote is how the source table looks like, second quote is how the result should look like.*

---

Hello everyone,

I have multiple parking that only sends changing states.
It sends a "1" when a car arrived at the parking, then it doesn't send anything until the car leaves again. At that moment the parking sends a "0". I need to do analysis over a long time, so it would be awesome to see the amount of time per hour or so to not get too many rows (compared by minute).

The data looks like this (as requested I reduce it to parking-ID 10 and just the last record from 19.12. and the records from 20.12.):

```
+------------+------------------+--------+-------------+
| Parking-ID | DateTime         | Status | Comment     |
+------------+------------------+--------+-------------+
| 10         | 20.12.2019 16:35 | 0      | Car left    |
+------------+------------------+--------+-------------+
| 10         | 20.12.2019 08:22 | 1      | Car arrived |
+------------+------------------+--------+-------------+
| 10         | 19.12.2019 22:47 | 0      | Car left    |
+------------+------------------+--------+-------------+
```

Now to not make it too easy for me, next to the "free" and "taken" status there is also a warm status. 1 hour after a car left the parking should be marked as "warm" because some cars have to come and go fast in a few minutes and this time range should be shown as "warm".

To not get too many rows (like for every minute), I would appreciate if it would be possible to get the summary per hour. For my analysis I should be able to see how many hours per day the parking was taken, how many hours it was warm and how many hours it was free.

So the result should look something like this (for Parking-ID 10 and for 20.12.2019):

```
+------------+------------------+--------+----------+---------+
| Parking-ID | DateTime         | Status | Duration | Comment |
+------------+------------------+--------+----------+---------+
| 10         | 20.12.2019 23:00 | 0      | 1.00     | Free    |
+------------+------------------+--------+----------+---------+
| 10         | 20.12.2019 22:00 | 0      | 1.00     | Free    |
+------------+------------------+--------+----------+---------+
| 10         | 20.12.2019 21:00 | 0      | 1.00     | Free    |
+------------+------------------+--------+----------+---------+
| 10         | 20.12.2019 20:00 | 0      | 1.00     | Free    |
+------------+------------------+--------+----------+---------+
| 10         | 20.12.2019 19:00 | 0      | 1.00     | Free    |
+------------+------------------+--------+----------+---------+
| 10         | 20.12.2019 18:00 | 0      | 1.00     | Free    |
+------------+------------------+--------+----------+---------+
| 10         | 20.12.2019 17:00 | 0      | 0.42     | Free    |
+------------+------------------+--------+----------+---------+
| 10         | 20.12.2019 17:00 | 2      | 0.58     | Warm    |
+------------+------------------+--------+----------+---------+
| 10         | 20.12.2019 16:00 | 2      | 0.42     | Warm    |
+------------+------------------+--------+----------+---------+
| 10         | 20.12.2019 16:00 | 1      | 0.58     | Taken   |
+------------+------------------+--------+----------+---------+
| 10         | 20.12.2019 15:00 | 1      | 1.00     | Taken   |
+------------+------------------+--------+----------+---------+
| 10         | 20.12.2019 14:00 | 1      | 1.00     | Taken   |
+------------+------------------+--------+----------+---------+
| 10         | 20.12.2019 13:00 | 1      | 1.00     | Taken   |
+------------+------------------+--------+----------+---------+
| 10         | 20.12.2019 12:00 | 1      | 1.00     | Taken   |
+------------+------------------+--------+----------+---------+
| 10         | 20.12.2019 11:00 | 1      | 1.00     | Taken   |
+------------+------------------+--------+----------+---------+
| 10         | 20.12.2019 10:00 | 1      | 1.00     | Taken   |
+------------+------------------+--------+----------+---------+
| 10         | 20.12.2019 09:00 | 1      | 1.00     | Taken   |
+------------+------------------+--------+----------+---------+
| 10         | 20.12.2019 08:00 | 1      | 0.63     | Taken   |
+------------+------------------+--------+----------+---------+
| 10         | 20.12.2019 08:00 | 0      | 0.37     | Free    |
+------------+------------------+--------+----------+---------+
| 10         | 20.12.2019 07:00 | 0      | 1.00     | Free    |
+------------+------------------+--------+----------+---------+
| 10         | 20.12.2019 06:00 | 0      | 1.00     | Free    |
+------------+------------------+--------+----------+---------+
| 10         | 20.12.2019 05:00 | 0      | 1.00     | Free    |
+------------+------------------+--------+----------+---------+
| 10         | 20.12.2019 04:00 | 0      | 1.00     | Free    |
+------------+------------------+--------+----------+---------+
| 10         | 20.12.2019 03:00 | 0      | 1.00     | Free    |
+------------+------------------+--------+----------+---------+
| 10         | 20.12.2019 02:00 | 0      | 1.00     | Free    |
+------------+------------------+--------+----------+---------+
| 10         | 20.12.2019 01:00 | 0      | 1.00     | Free    |
+------------+------------------+--------+----------+---------+
| 10         | 20.12.2019 00:00 | 0      | 1.00     | Free    |
+------------+------------------+--------+----------+---------+
```

Does someone have a good approach? I already searched and tried but couldn't find a working approach.

Thank you and best regards

Comment: IMO,Output is not as per given input.Can you fast change input as per given output, so that it is clear. (Input for Parking-ID 10 and for 20.12.2019)

Comment: can you please add what is the expected result

Comment: I changed the example.
@KumarHarsh The input for 20.12. and output for 20.12. should now match

Comment: @KrishnaMuppalla The second table is the expected result.

Comment: @denzel, plz check my answer and above all clear the doubt,nicely.

Answer (score 1):

`First`, your duration output is still wrong,if you cross check.
For example 20.12.2019 08:00 it should be 22.00 and 38.00.Clear this ?

`Secondly`,Two rows on for `20.12.2019 17:00` is not clear.Why it it will contain 2 rows ?Clear this also.

```
Create Calendar table in whatever way you want.

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CalendarDate](
[Dates] [datetime2](0) NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [Dates] ASC
)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

insert into [CalendarDate] with(tablock)
select top (100000) 
dateadd(day,ROW_NUMBER()over(order by (select null))
,'1950-01-01 00:00:00') 
from sys.objects a, sys.objects b, sys.objects c
```

Then Create number table also

```
 -- Real or #temp your wish
create Table #Number(Hrs int)
insert into #Number (Hrs)
select top 24 ROW_NUMBER()over(order by number)-1 
from master..spt_values
```

Your table sample data.I have kept Parking status in seperate table,follow Normalization.

```
-- your real table
create table #Parking( ParkingID int, ParkingDateTime Datetime2(0),ParkingStatus tinyint  )
insert into #Parking values(10,'2019-12-20 16:35',0),(10,'2019-12-20 08:22',1)
,(10,'2019-12-19 22:47',0)

-- It should be your real table
create table #ParkingStatus( ParkingStatus tinyint,StatusName varchar(50)  )
insert into #ParkingStatus values(0,'Car left')
,(1,'Car arrived'),(2,'Free'),(3,'Taken')
,(4,'Warm')
```

The Script,

```
declare @From Datetime2(0)='2019-12-20'
declare @To Datetime2(0)=dateadd(second,-1,dateadd(day,1,@From))

 -- Put require data in #temp table,since it will be use many times
create table #ParkingTemp(ParkingID int,ParkingDateTime Datetime2(0)
,ParkingDate Date,ParkingStatus tinyint )

insert into #ParkingTemp (ParkingID,ParkingDateTime
,ParkingDate,ParkingStatus)
select P.ParkingID,ParkingDateTime
,p.ParkingDateTime 
,ParkingStatus
 from #Parking P
where ParkingDateTime>=@From
and ParkingDateTime<=@To



;With CTE as
(
select ParkingID,ParkingDateTime ,count(*)+1 SplitCount
,ParkingStatus as InitialStatus
from #ParkingTemp
group by ParkingID,ParkingDateTime,ParkingStatus
)
, DistinctIDCTE as
(
select distinct ParkingID
 from #ParkingTemp

)
, CTE1 as 
(
select Dates 
,dateadd(hour,hrs,Dates)ReportDateTime
,ParkingID
from [CalendarDate],#Number N,DistinctIDCTE
where dates>=@From and Dates<=@To
),
CTE2 as
(
select c.ParkingID
,dateadd(minute,-datepart(minute,ParkingDateTime),ParkingDateTime) ParkingDate
,ParkingDateTime,hrs as rownum,InitialStatus
 from CTE C
cross apply(select hrs from #Number N where c.SplitCount>n.Hrs)ca
)
,CTE3 as
(
select parkingid,ParkingDateTime as FromDatetime 
,ToDatetime
from #ParkingTemp C
cross apply(select top 1 ParkingDateTime as ToDatetime 
from #ParkingTemp C1 where c.ParkingID=c1.ParkingID
and  c1.ParkingStatus=0 and 
c1.ParkingDateTime>c.ParkingDateTime 
order by c1.ParkingDateTime  )c1
where ParkingStatus=1
)
,CTE4 as
(
select c.ParkingID,c.ReportDateTime
from CTE1 C
outer apply(select top 1 FromDatetime ,ToDatetime
from  CTE3 c1 where c.ParkingID=c1.ParkingID
 and (ReportDateTime>= FromDatetime and ReportDateTime<=ToDatetime))ca
  )

  --select * from CTE2
 ,CTE5 as
 (
  select c4.ParkingID,c4.ReportDateTime
  ,case when rownum=0 and InitialStatus=1 then 2
  when rownum=1 and InitialStatus=1 then 3
  when rownum=0 and InitialStatus=0 then 4
  when rownum=1 and InitialStatus=0 then 3
  else 2 end as ParkingStatusid
  ,case when rownum=0  then datediff(minute,ReportDateTime,ParkingDateTime)
  when rownum=1 then 60- datepart(minute,ParkingDateTime)
  else 1.00 end Duration
  ,ParkingDateTime
  ,rownum,InitialStatus
  from CTE4 c4
  left join CTE2 c2 on c4.ParkingID=c2.ParkingID and c2.ParkingDate =c4.ReportDateTime

   )

   select c5.ParkingID,c5.ReportDateTime,c5.ParkingStatusid
   ,Duration,PS.StatusName AS Comment
   from CTE5 c5
   inner join #ParkingStatus ps on c5.ParkingStatusid=ps.ParkingStatus
    order by ReportDateTime desc
```

Clean Up

```
drop table #Parking,#ParkingStatus,#Number,#ParkingTemp
```

**Alternate and improve :**

```
;WITH CTE
     AS (SELECT ParkingID,
                ParkingDateTime,
                COUNT(*) + 1 SplitCount,
                ParkingStatus AS InitialStatus
         FROM #ParkingTemp
         GROUP BY ParkingID,
                  ParkingDateTime,
                  ParkingStatus),
     DistinctIDCTE
     AS (SELECT DISTINCT
                ParkingID
         FROM #ParkingTemp),
     CTE1
     AS (SELECT Dates,
                DATEADD(hour, hrs, Dates) ReportDateTime,
                ParkingID
         FROM [CalendarDate],
              #Number N,
              DistinctIDCTE
         WHERE dates >= @From
               AND Dates <= @To),
     CTE2
     AS (SELECT c.ParkingID,
                DATEADD(minute, -DATEPART(minute, ParkingDateTime), ParkingDateTime) ParkingDate,
                ParkingDateTime,
                hrs AS rownum,
                InitialStatus
         FROM CTE C
              CROSS APPLY
         (
             SELECT hrs
             FROM #Number N
             WHERE c.SplitCount > n.Hrs
         ) ca),
     CTE5
     AS (SELECT c4.ParkingID,
                c4.ReportDateTime,
                CASE
                    WHEN rownum = 0
                         AND InitialStatus = 1
                    THEN 2
                    WHEN rownum = 1
                         AND InitialStatus = 1
                    THEN 3
                    WHEN rownum = 0
                         AND InitialStatus = 0
                    THEN 4
                    WHEN rownum = 1
                         AND InitialStatus = 0
                    THEN 3
                    ELSE 2
                END AS ParkingStatusid,
                CASE
                    WHEN rownum = 0
                    THEN DATEDIFF(minute, ReportDateTime, ParkingDateTime)
                    WHEN rownum = 1
                    THEN 60 - DATEPART(minute, ParkingDateTime)
                    ELSE 1.00
                END Duration,
                ParkingDateTime,
                rownum,
                InitialStatus
         FROM CTE1 c4
              LEFT JOIN CTE2 c2 ON c4.ParkingID = c2.ParkingID
                                   AND c2.ParkingDate = c4.ReportDateTime)
     SELECT c5.ParkingID,
            c5.ReportDateTime,
            c5.ParkingStatusid,
            Duration,
            PS.StatusName AS Comment
     FROM CTE5 c5
          INNER JOIN #ParkingStatus ps ON c5.ParkingStatusid = ps.ParkingStatus
     ORDER BY ReportDateTime DESC;
```

**Note** : clear my doubts.Throw diffrent sample data such within one hour there more than 2 parking staus for same parkingid.

Comment: @denzel, check Alternate and improve , Note